# How to use AWS S3 (Amazon Web Service) in WP8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, amazon-s3

Could someone guide me or give me a headstart on how to begin with AWS s3.

I need to use it in my wp8 silverlight app.

I am aware of the nuGet package. But unable to find a decent tutorial or sample code for WP8.

Prompt reply will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Minio .NET Library for Amazon S3 Compatible Cloud Storage](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet)

Also check [Examples directory](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/tree/master/Minio.Examples) to get an better idea of using it.

Hope it helps.